# Why does the method of Lagrange multiplier fail?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

**Question**

Let $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ be two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and $f$ be a function defined by $f(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}) := \mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{y}$. Can this function be minimised subject to the conditions $\parallel \mathbf{x} \parallel = \parallel \mathbf{y} \parallel = 1$, with the method of Lagrange multiplier?

**Attempt**

I failed to used Lagrange multiplier to solve this question. The primary reason is that as I try to express $f$ as a function of four variables $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$, the gradient of $g_1$ and the gradient of $g_2$ has the last two entries being $0$. While the gradient of $f$ does not have zero elements. Thus, it seems there can be no $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ that equates the three gradient vectors. Am I correct? Or am I grossly simplifying the question when I express $f$ as a function of four variables?

Comment: When you have 2 constraints the associated system of equations is $\nabla f = \lambda \nabla g_1 + \mu \nabla g_2$ rather than $\nabla f = \lambda \nabla g_1$ AND $\nabla f = \mu g_2$

Comment: See example here: http://mathonline.wikidot.com/lagrange-multipliers-with-two-constraints-examples-3#toc0

Comment: Also another way :   Notice that $$- \|x\| ~ \|y\| \leq  \langle x ,y \rangle$$

Comment: @Redshoes Probably it was his intent to prove that inequality with Lagrange multipliers

Comment: @Federico If that would be orginal question, I would fix $y$ and just minimize $x.y$ over the constraint $\|x\|^2 = 1$.  Then we have a mode with less variable and one constraint (only one Lagrange multiplier ). so much easier to solve.

Comment: I mean, whatever, my understanding is not that he's trying to minimize $x\cdot y$, but that he's trying to do it *with Lagrangr multipliers*.

Comment: Probably he took this as a toy example to understand Lagrange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f,g_1,g_2:\mathbb R^{2d}\to\mathbb R$ be given by
$$
f(x,y)=x\cdot y \qquad g_1(x,y)=\|x\|^2 \qquad g_2(x,y)=\|y\|^2.
$$
You want to minimize $f$ subject to $g_1=g_2=1$. Then
$$
\nabla f(x,y) = (y,x) \qquad \nabla g_1(x,y) = (2x, 0) \qquad \nabla g_2(x,y) = (0, 2y).
$$
From [Lagrange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier#Multiple_constraints) you get
$$
(y,x) = \lambda_1(2x,0) + \lambda_2(0,2y) = 2(\lambda_1 x, \lambda_2 y).
$$
From this you get that $x$ and $y$ bust be linearly dependent, hence $y=\pm x$ because of the constraint. $y=-x$ is a global minimizer, $y=x$ is a global maximizer.